# What is the Razor command used to make a click event to a controller in with no postback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any special command to make a click event with Razor and without a postback. Is it only using jQuery and using a javascript function?. Help?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code as part of your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Ajax.BeginForm`.There will still be a postback(in the background) but because it's done via AJAX it will not be seen by the user.Try the code below, just make sure you add a reference to the jQuery and the unobtrusive-ajax.js libraries.

**Controller:**

```
public string GreetUser(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GreetUser", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions() 
{
     UpdateTargetId ="result"
}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("name", null, new { style = "width:200px;" })
    <input type="submit" value="Greet" />
}
<div id="result"></div>
```